# glm::dot returns a vector

Tags: c++, vector, glm-math

My vectors are declared as follows:

```
std::vector<double> vec1;
std::vector<double> vec2;

double result = glm::dot(vec1, vec2);
```

I receive the following error: `error: no viable conversion from 'std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >' to 'double'`

Shouldn't `glm::dot` return a scalar value (a `double`) in this case?

Comment: Why not use the glm vector types, e.g. `glm::dvec3`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be mistaking myself, but this error must come from the argument type, not the return type , glm::dot has never taken any std::vector as argument, and as it's not a vec2 or vec3, etc. (not a glm type), it may try to cast it to a 1 dimension value to perform a 1 dimension scalar product

Answer (score 1):

As Guiroux said, the first issue is that you are using std::vector instead a glm vector (such as vec3 for instance). On the other hand, after changing that you will get an invalid conversion between vec3 and float

You could try this:

```
glm::vec3 a;
glm::vec3 b;
glm::dot<3, float, glm::qualifier::highp>(a, b);
```

Since GLM has two methods dot

```
template<typename T>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER T dot(T x, T y)
{
    GLM_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "'dot' accepts only floating-point inputs");
    return x * y;
}
template<length_t L, typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER T dot(vec<L, T, Q> const& x, vec<L, T, Q> const& y)
{
    GLM_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "'dot' accepts only floating-point inputs");
    return detail::compute_dot<vec<L, T, Q>, T, detail::is_aligned<Q>::value>::call(x, y);
}
```

The compiler is assuming that T is vec3 and for that reason is using the first method

Take a look at this post:

[Templates C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/)

> In this specific case where the generic type T is used as a parameter
>   for GetMax the compiler can find out automatically which data type has
>   to instantiate without having to explicitly specify it within angle
>   brackets (like we have done before specifying  and ). So we
>   could have written instead: int i,j; GetMax (i,j);

Answer (score 0):

Just to re-iterate what has been said above, try this:

```
glm::dvec3 vec1;
glm::dvec3 vec2;
double result = glm::dot(vec1, vec2);
```

Comment: This does not work.
The glm::dot will try complain that there is an invalid conversion between double and dvec3.

Comment: Really? I just looked at my code again, and it works for me. If you give it two dvec3's, then you get a double.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out, the CLion IDE is really new and is not working well sometimes. My bad, it was giving an error because it couldn't  deal with the function template.